# Select all javascript logic for multiple rows

Tags: javascript, checkbox, selectall

I have the following Javascript function that is called when a change is made to one of my five "select-all" buttons of the class 'checkAllAud'. I basically have 5 vertical rows with possibly hundreds of checkboxes under each that need to be checked/unchecked.

**My current code has problems with it when you want to click select all on all 5 columns, only every other column has all of its checkboxes selected. So my question is how can I rewrite this code so it will work with my multiple instances of select all columns and checkboxes.**

```
var toggle = true;
    //on click function  here
    $(".checkAllAud").change(function() {
        var toggled = $(this).val();
                //alert('checkallaud function triggered');
                toggleBox(toggled);
            });
    //end on click function
    function toggleBox(toggled) {
        var objList = document.getElementsByName(toggled)
    //alert('toggleBox function triggered');
    for(i = 0; i < objList.length; i++)
        objList[i].checked = toggle;

    toggle = !toggle;
}
```

here is how my code currently works

```
            column1   column 2   column 3   column 4   column 5
(select all) [x]        [x]         [x]        [x]        [x]
             [x]        [ ]         [x]        [ ]        [x]
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8KQcp/8/

Comment: Please consider creating a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) or JSFiddle with some markup and a simplified example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: sure, I can make a jsfiddle if that makes things easier

Comment: @NickTomlin posted the link to jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a global, just take the checked state from the input you changed ;-)

```
$(".checkAllAud").change(function() {
   var toggled = $(this).val();
   //alert('checkallaud function triggered');
   toggleBox(toggled, this.checked);
});

function toggleBox(toggled, checked) {
   var objList = document.getElementsByName(toggled)
   //alert('toggleBox function triggered');
   for(i = 0; i < objList.length; i++)
      objList[i].checked = checked;

}
```

**working jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/8KQcp/9/

---

**Improvement:** http://jsbin.com/cakogulu/1/

```
$(".checkAllAud").change(function() {
   $('input[name^="' + this.value + '"]:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Works for me, I didn't know you could use the checked state; I thought  variables were needed

Comment: I edited my answer with an improvement to your code ;-) nota bene: `checkAllAud` values are just names, (no more array names)

Comment: [According to jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/), "*Because `:checkbox` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:checkbox` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `[type="checkbox"]` instead*"

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a little html augmentation before you assign your event handlers.

Here is a fiddle for this example:

[See fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/AFNb4/1/)

You need your javascript to iterate through an html structure that is repeatable.  So, say you have an html structure like this:  (see the fiddle)

```
<table class="jsSelectAll">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="select-all">
            <td>Select All</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row Label</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row Label</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="select-all">
            <td>Select All</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row Label</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then, I would consider breaking out each table and tbody within the table as you need to, and add row (if desired) and column pointers to the checkboxes.  Also, I would use closures to make the event wiring a bit easier, like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // closures
    var $tables = $('table.jsSelectAll');

    $tables.each(function () {
        // closures
        var $table = $(this);
        var $tbodies = $table.find('tbody');

        $tbodies.each(function () {
            // closures
            var $tbody = $(this);
            var $rows = $tbody.find('tr');
            var $selectAllCheckboxes = $tbody.find('.select-all input[type="checkbox"]');
            var $allCheckboxes = $tbody.find('tr td input[type="checkbox"]')

            // label data cells with rows(if desired) and collumns
            $rows.each(function (rowIndex) {
                // closures
                var $row = $(this);
                var $inputs = $row.find('input[type="checkbox"]');

                $row.attr('data-row', rowIndex);
                $inputs.each(function (colIndex) {
                    // closures
                    $cbx = $(this);

                    $cbx.attr('data-col', colIndex);
                });
            });

            // wire select all for each select-all row checkbox
            $selectAllCheckboxes.each(function () {
                // closures
                var $cbx = $(this)
                var fClick = function () {
                    var iCol = $cbx.attr('data-col');
                    $allCheckboxes
                        .filter('[data-col="' + iCol + '"]')
                        .each(function () {
                            $(this).prop('checked', true);
                        });
                };
                $cbx.click(fClick);
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It almost feels like we are using a sledgehammer to kill a gnat. *.*

Comment: HAHA!  Well, this way, you can have as many tables and tbody groups on a page as you would want.